# ISchedulerProvider / IScheduler - how to introduce multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, reactive-programming

I have a public interface IScheduleProvider, contaiing afew ISchedulers(UiScheduler / BackgroundScheduler / etc) with get methods.

The UI-side subscribes to updates from the Server-side, using 
...
.ObserveOn(UiScheduler)
.Subscribe(...)

So this means that all the updates from server is queued on the UiScheduler in order, in line with reactive architecture.

However it is observed that there is only 1 thread being used for all tasks.

How can the multithreading be introduced in this case?

Comment: Please post your actual `IScheduleProvider` interface code and its implementation. What specific Reactive library are you using?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve"

Comment: What programming language and platform are you targeting? `UiScheduler` is a class in React-Cocoa for the Swift and Objective-C programming languages, not C# ( http://reactivecocoa.io/reactiveswift/docs/latest/Classes/UIScheduler.html ).